# Where can I find a list of batch script options?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, method-call

I have .bat script file that contains commands like these:

```
call %CONAN_BAT% install cmake/3.21.1@thirdparty/stable -g=virtualenv -if "%BUILD_DIR%" -pr vs2010
```

Even with google I failed to figure out what anything besides the `call` command and the variables `%CONAN_BAT%` and `%BUILD_DIR%` mean. Everything else I cannot find any resource on.

`install cmake/3.21.1@thirdparty/stable` at least is kinda self explanatory but I still do not know why it works as I can find no `install` command for batch scripts. The remaining options(?) `-g`, `-if` and `-pr` with their corresponding values are completely lost on me.

Can anyone explain to me what is going on and maybe link me a resource where shorthand options like these are explained?

Comment: The install command has nothing to do with anything `cmd` related. `%CONAN_BAT%` is a paramater that contains the path to another `batch-file`. That batch-file then accepts paramaters, one being `install` another `-g` etc. Find that batch file and you will see what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A search for `conan install` returns a link to [conan documentation](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/consumer/install.html) with descriptions of all parameters.